# Xamarin UnsatisfiedLinkError arm64-v8a

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue where I am trying to use a binding project for an Android Application.

I get an UnsatisfiedLinkException  error like so:

```
Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/TestSDK.TestSDK-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/TestSDK.TestSDK-1/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/TestSDK.TestSDK-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libcreatedata.so"
```

So from the looks of it, it's an issue with the arm64-v8a architecture.

In the binding project I added a folder for that architecture like so:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBEe7.png)

The code seems to run on an armaebi VM but I need it to work in the arm64-v8a architecture (as I need bluetooth to connect to a printer).

The architectures are selected in the advanced settings like so

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqd2R.png)

I can't see what else I would need to do to sort this. Although I am not familiar with Xamarin, but familiar with C# etc.

Comment: You could add `arm64` and `x86` supported architectures in your `Advanced Android Options`, then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried this and still the same error. Any other thoughts?

Comment: hi, any help? I get same error